# table isn't aligned centering when use ccaption and threeparttable

Tags: tables, threeparttable

I'm using a template to write my thesis. This template uses `ccaption` to make bilingual caption, but I found that I can't make table centering when I use `threeparttable` together. Here is my mwe

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{ccaption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \centering
    \bicaption{Short}{Long}{Bild}{Langlauf}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c} \hline 
        testtest & testtest\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
    \item[a] note
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: table]

Both `\centering` didn't work, how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{ccaption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
        \centering
        \bicaption{Short}{Long}{Bild}{Langlauf}
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \begin{tabular}{c|c} \hline 
                testtest & testtest\\\hline
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tablenotes}
                \item[a] note
            \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Some might say that placing the `\bicaption` directive outside the `threeparttable` environment defeats the entire purpose of using a `threeparttable`. (The three formal parts of a `threeparttable` environment are the caption, the `tabular`-like environment, and the `tablenotes` environment.)

Comment: Thanks! It works, actually I just want to use the `tablenote` function after a table.